# Pagination in WordPress page not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the WordPress theme mystile and the WooCommerce plugin, but the paging does not work properly. The paging appears only on the home page, but it does not appear on other pages.
I would like to put pagination on all pages, but I can not. I also want to limit the number of products that appear on the home page. Right now, 12 products always appear, but I would like only 8 to appear.

Can someone help me?

Comment: May I take a look at your site first?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this code on page.php and single.php

```
<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p></div>
```

Regarding the product count, please go to Settings->Reading

Comment: thanks for the reply friend but did not work
where in the single.php and page.php I put these tags? I do not know very well wordpress